# Conditional use in view for SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mvvm, conditional-statements

I have a model with data string of `name` and a bool of `UE`. I'm trying to display `item.name` whenever `UE` is true. My issue is when whenever I run the code the data doesn't seem to read the  `UE`. I got an error displaying the `item.UE` as a text view. The data that I am getting it from is from a database the `item.name` works without the conditional.

```
struct AttendingUsersView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = UserViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List (model.list) { item in
                if item.UE == true {
                    Text(item.name)
                } else {
                    Text("This isnt working")
                }
            }

            
            DismissButton
        }
    }
```

I've tried displaying the `item.UE` to see what it would display but I get an error saying "No exact matches in call to initializer".

`UserViewModel` file

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var list = [Username]()
    
    
    func addData(name: String, UE: Bool) {
        
        //get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        
        // Add a new document in collection "username"
        db.collection("usernames").document(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "value") as! String).setData([
                // MARK: Change the parameters to the users inputed choices
                "name": name,
                "UE": UE
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }
    }
    
    
    func getData() {
        
        //get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        //Read the documents at a specific path
        db.collection("usernames").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            //checking for errors
            if error == nil {
                //no errors
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    // update
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        // Get all the documents and create usernames
                        self.list = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            
                            //Create a Username
                            return Username(id: d.documentID, name: d["name"] as? String ?? "", UE: (d["UE"] != nil)) //cast as a string and if not found return as a empty string 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //Handle the error
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

`Username` model

```
struct Username: Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var ue: Bool
    
}
```

Comment: Without showing the code for whatever type `item` is, this isn't possible to debug

Comment: where would i find that? wouldn't item be whatever the iteration be for the model.list inside the body?

Comment: We don't see any code for `UserViewModel`, so I don't know what type `item` is. I don't know where to find that in your code.

Comment: I added the code for `UserViewModel` thanks for the input.

Comment: You didn't include `Username`, which is apparently the type of `item`, but it does clear some things up. What do you mean by "it doesn't read the `UE`?

Comment: I have `UE` set as a bool so i set it as false but the condition still passes.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. `ue` != `UE`. Without a [mre], it's impossible to diagnose this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with fixes for your `ue` in your `getData`, and
in the view display.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AttendingUsersView()
    }
}

struct AttendingUsersView: View {
    @StateObject var model = UserViewModel()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List (model.list) { item in
                if item.ue {  // <-- here
                    Text(item.name)
                } else {
                    Text("This is working ue is false")
                }
            }
           // DismissButton
        }
    }
}

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // for testing
    @Published var list:[Username] = [Username(id: "1", name: "item-1", ue: false),
                                    Username(id: "2", name: "item-2", ue: true),
                                    Username(id: "3", name: "item-3", ue: false)]
    
    func addData(name: String, UE: Bool) {
        //get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        // Add a new document in collection "username"
        db.collection("usernames").document(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "value") as! String).setData([
            // MARK: Change the parameters to the users inputed choices
            "name": name,
            "UE": UE
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        //get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        //Read the documents at a specific path
        db.collection("usernames").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            //checking for errors
            if error == nil {
                //no errors
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    // update
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // Get all the documents and create usernames
                        self.list = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            //Create a Username
                            // -- here, ue:
                            return Username(id: d.documentID, name: d["name"] as? String ?? "", ue: (d["UE"] != nil)) // <-- here ue:
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Username: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var ue: Bool
}
```